# Whenever I try to issue the 'rails s' command in Aptana Studios it comes up with an error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, aptana

When I issue the command `$ rails s` in Aptana Studio's inbuilt command line, it comes up with this error and I don't know how it can be fixed the for the project can be found at https://github.com/nathandunn97/sample_app

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /home/nathan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/sample
_application/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_sample_application_session'
                              ^
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/nathan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/sample_application/config/environment.rb:5
        from /home/nathan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/sample_application/config.ru:4:in `require'
        from /home/nathan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/sample_application/config.ru:4
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from /home/nathan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/sample_application/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /home/nathan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/sample_application/config.ru:1
```

Answer (score 0):

The new ruby hash syntax (`key:`), is only available to ruby 1.9 and beyond. We can see from your log that you are using the 1.8 version.

Comment: I've done `ruby -v` in the command line and it says I have version: `ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]` and the problem is still persisting